# Regex.Replace unable to make it work

Tags: regex, vb.net, replace

I would expect following code to replace every occurence of whitespace+digit+whitespace but it is replacing anything+digit+anything.

```
nswapfirstpart = Regex.Replace(nswapfirstpart, "\W[0-9]\W", " _ ")
```

Thanks

Comment: `"\s[0-9]\s"` instead of `"\W[0-9]\W"`.

Comment: great! thanks! could you post it as answer so i can accept it please? also please could you explain why it is like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `\W` which refers to a non-word character and is denoted by

```
[^A-Za-z0-9_]
```

So it would match special characters, spaces, essentially everything that it not an alphabet, digit or underscore.

You need to use `\s` which denotes whitespace characters and is denoted by

```
[ \t\r\n\v\f]
```

As such, use:

```
"\s[0-9]\s"
```

instead of

```
"\W[0-9]\W"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "\s[0-9]\s" "\s" is for white space and '\w' is for word

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not matching **anything** it is matching non alphanumeric, which is just what the \W option does. That is  the equvalent of

`swapfirstpart = Regex.Replace(nswapfirstpart, "[^a-zA-Z0-9_][0-9][^a-zA-Z0-9_]", " _ ")`

If you want a white space, then don't use \W use \s or even just " " if what you want is actually a space.

Regular expressions are an entire language unto themselves, very expressive and very powerful -- and as with any programming languages, it does what you say not what you want. Be precise in what you say.